# Avoid text going under menu - Twitter bootstrap affix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a little problem, and I need your help to resolv it.

I have a navbar with a span12 and an affix. The scroll works, but text always go under the navbar, when I click on an item, I can't see the title I just clicked on, and that's what I'm searching for.
 I actually have this :

```
<div class="container" id="all">        
<div class="row">
<!-- Navbar
                ================================================== -->              

                    <div id="navbar" class="span12" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="56">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            <li><a href="#menu1">Qui suis-je ? </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu2">Ce que je peux apporter </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu3">Mon expérience </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu4">Mon parcours scolaire </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu5">Contactez-moi ! </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="span12 content">
                            <section id="menu0">
                                <h1>MOIIII</h1>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </section>
                    <section id="menu1">
                        <h1>Qui suis-je ? </h1>
                        <p>.</p>
                      </section>

                      <section id="menu2">
                        <h1>Ce que je peux apporter </h1>
                         <p></p>
                      </section>

                      <section id="menu3">
                        <h1>Mon expérience </h1>
                         <p></p>
                      </section>

                      <section id="menu4">
                        <h1>Mon parcours scolaire </h1>
                         <p></p>
                      </section>

                      <section id="menu5">
                        <h1>Contactez-moi ! </h1>
                         <p></p>
                      </section>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the CSS

```
    body {
        background: #CCC;
    }


    #all {
        margin-top:55px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: #EEE;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

    #navbar {
        height: 80px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
        top:0px;
    }

    .affix {
        position: fixed; 
        top:0px;
    }

    #navbar li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px; 
        padding: 25px;
    }

    #navbar a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }

    #navbar .active a {
        color: red;
    }
```

You can have an idea of what I mean here : http://jsfiddle.net/yPgUu/626/

Thanks,

Kai23

Comment: What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: Just that my text can be seen even if I click on the menu. Something like this : [- Exemple -](http://pixeldizajn.com/PerfectCV/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the existing answers, try adding some padding to the top of your `legends` in order to push each block below the navigation:

```
fieldset legend {
    padding-top:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JHLVd/1/

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted. That's the little things... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply give the `.nav-list` a background color to prevent the text from getting cluttered.

```
.nav-list{background: #eee;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yPgUu/631/

**Update** to address the edited question

You could add a left margin to push the `.nav-list` toward the center:

```
.nav-list{margin: 0 200px;}
```